# what is the issue with my shiny code that is not spitting out the ggplot plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am new to making shiny apps. Essentially I am trying to make a shiny app that does the following:

1. ui allows you to load a df from your local computer
2. the df is read and then the user can select two other inputs from drop down menu -column names from the dataframe to plot a ggplot
3. gives the output ggplot

Here is what is happening

1. the df is read in fine
2. the dropdown select menu input in the ui work fine
3. the ggplot is just not responsive

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Upload Excel Sheet"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose Excel Sheet",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv")),
     selectInput("x", "X-axis", choices = ""),
     selectInput("y", "Y-axis", choices = "")
     ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  data <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
        if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
        read_excel(inFile$datapath)
  })
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "x", choices = names(data()))
    updateSelectInput(session, "y", choices = names(data()))
  })
  
  output$plot1<- renderPlot({
    data()%>%ggplot(aes(x=input$x, y=input$y))+geom_bar(stat="identity"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What I have tried:

1. I have replaced the plot output (renderPlot) with a table output (renderTable) and see that the code "reads" the df and spits out the table.
2. I have pulled the df in a separate piece of code (read_excel) into R and then run the ggplot command on it and it seems to be working fine.

I feel like I am missing something obvious here, and perhaps something critically basic. If possible please try the code on any excel sheet in your local dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things need to be adjusted here.

1. There is an extra close-paren with `geom_bar(stat="identity"))`, removed.
2. `ggplot2` aesthetics need to be either non-standard evaluation *symbols* (not workable here), or we need to use a technique described here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html#using-aes-and-vars-in-a-package-function-1. Namely, `.data[[varname]]` (with strings) or `{{ varname }}` (with user-provided NSE symbols). We'll use the former here.

Some optional things for more resiliency (and good code practices):

3. I suggest the use of `req(.)` liberally. See my examples. It not only handles some of the `if (is.null(..))` you have to deal with, it also very well handles  downstream reactivity.
4. You allow `".csv"` but always use `read_excel`, I've fixed that by including a simple `if`.

Code.

```r
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  data <- reactive({
    req(inFile <- input$file1$datapath)
    if (grepl("csv$", inFile)) {
      read.csv(inFile)
    } else {
      read_excel(inFile$datapath)
    }
  })
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "x", choices = names(data()))
    updateSelectInput(session, "y", choices = names(data()))
  })
  
  output$plot1<- renderPlot({
    req(data(), input$x, input$y)
    data() %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=.data[[ input$x ]], y=.data[[ input$y ]])) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity")
  })
}
```

---

Extension: in addition to `req`, I also recommend becoming familiar with `validate` and `need`. For instance, if we update your `data <- reactive(.)` to be:

```r
  data <- reactive({
    req(inFile <- input$file1$datapath)
    if (grepl("csv$", inFile)) {
      out <- readr::read_csv(inFile)
    } else {
      out <- readr::read_excel(inFile$datapath)
    }
    isnum <- sapply(out, is.numeric)
    validate(
      need(sum(isnum) >= 2, "We need at least two numeric columns")
    )
    out
  })
```

(*and no other changes anywhere else*), then all dependent reactive blocks "see" the problem. For instance, if I feed a CSV with insufficient numeric columns, we see

[image: shiny app with a failing 'validate' need]

where we would normally see

[image: shiny app with successful 'validate' need]

(where the plot is peeking out on the bottom).

Comment: First, thank you for the detailed explanation. You bring up some interesting points and your guide to using req is really great - I will be sure to use it going forward, and liberally too. However, running this server code appears to throw the following error and does not generate a ggplot output
"""Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"""

Thank you also for providing the link to using ggplot aethetics.

Comment: Not sure what to make of your error. Try adding `browser()` in the relevant reactive blocks after the `req(.)` lines then step through interactively what's going on.

Comment: Appears to be an issue with the format of excel file, because the mtcars dataset runs fine with your code. Thank you so much, again, for the detailed explanation. I learnt much more than I asked for!

Comment: Glad you resolved it!